# How to suppress prompt when passing through remaining args

Tags: powershell

I'm making a powershell script that has to read the first argument provided to it and use it as a parameter, however all remaining arguments need to be passed through to the command it's calling.

Unfortunately, the code I currently have seems to be causing this to happen:

```
cmdlet Write-Output at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters: 
InputObject[0]:
```

Here's what I've got for my script:

```
param(    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $entrypoint,
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $remainingArgs
)

$containerName = docker-compose run `
    --rm `
    -d `
    --entrypoint=$entrypoint `
    webapp "$remainingArgs"
```

I'm coming from a bash background, so I'm sure there's likely an assumption or two here that I've made that isn't quite right.  But as you can see, all I want is all remaining parameters in `$remainingArgs` to be tacked on to the end of the command I'm calling.

I should also note that sometimes there are no `$remainingArgs`.  It can be either empty, or have one or more values.

Comment: I do not see relation between prompt and your code. Prompt is about calling `Write-Output` without specifying anything to mandatory parameter `InputObject`. But your code does not contains call to `Write-Object` or its aliases `echo` and `write`.

Comment: Can you show us a sample function call? It shows the issue with `pipeline position 1` so I am curious to see that.

Comment: It's not a function, it's just a whole command.  I call it just by going `command param1 param2 param3 param4`.  Pretty simple.

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to reproduce the problem with what you posted. Is the above the entire code in your script? And how *exactly* are you running it? Please do not paraphrase.